# How to call another github action inside a docker action shell script?

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions

Say I have a Docker container GitHub action: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action

When writing the `entrypoint.sh` file for this action instead of simple code, can I call another GitHub action?

Is this possible at all?

I am trying to add a new feature/new action to an existing GitHub action that's in Docker style. Simple shell scripts cannot work. Is there a way to call another GitHub action within the shell script?

Comment: It's not possible :/ Among [the different types of actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#types-of-actions), only a composite action allows allows you to combine multiple workflow steps (commands or other actions) within one action.